# Should I manually maintain the lifecycle of IHostedService?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, background-process

Should we under any circumstances try to manually invoke the lifecycle methods of ASP .net Core IHostedService? The MSDN documentations I read so far do not seem to mention that anywhere, it's more likely to be coupled tightly with app lifespan.

The other doubt I have is even if we do invoke StartAsync/StopAsync, is there anyway to tell the application not to invoke StartAsync when application loads?

I know this is kind of duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51469881/asp-net-core-ihostedservice-manual-start-stop-pause),but the post didn't really answer my query.

Comment: What does it mean to "manually invoe the lifecycle methods" on a hosted service and why do you want to do that: what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Ok..so my target is to start a background service on ad hoc basis as per requirement, let it continue to run until a cancellation signal comes. I don't want this to start with application. Does IHostedService fit here?