# How To Send A Cancellation Token To A Background Service In Blazor Server

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, background-service

I am trying to add a start and stop functionality to a long-running background service in my Blazor server app by the press of a button(s). The background service, `PeriodicExecutor`, is started without any user interaction in the startup.cs file and works as expected:

**startup.cs**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddHostedService<PeriodicExecutor>();
        }
```

Below is the essential code in the background service:

**PeriodicExecutor.cs**

```
 public class PeriodicExecutor : BackgroundService
    {
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is the essential code in the base class that handles the code for the button `onclick()` events:

**IndexBase.cs**

```
    public class IndexBase : ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject]
        IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {

        }

        protected async Task StartService()
        {
            if (!PeriodicExecutor.status)
            {
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Microservice Started");
            }
            else
            {
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Microservice Already Running");
            }
        }
        protected async Task StopService()
        {
            if (PeriodicExecutor.status) 
            {
                
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Microservice Stopped");
            }
            else
            {
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Microservice Already Stopped");
            }
        }
    }
```

So the question is, how can i stop the backgroundservice with a cancellation token from the `StopService()` method and start the background service in the `StartService()` method? Any detailed answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you use a CancellationTokenSource?

Comment: I think the point of a "BackgroundService" is it runs in the background.  I don't think you start and stop them from the UI or any other front end process.  `ExecuteAsync` and `StopAsync` are called by the service container.  If you want some sort of timer process that you control from the UI then why not use a normal service with some control mechanisms?

Comment: I didn't try it but this might help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51469881/asp-net-core-ihostedservice-manual-start-stop-pause